# Error while fitting data in auto.arima - R

Tags: r, time-series, arima, seasonality, error-message

I am running `auto.arima` for forecasting time series data and getting the following error:

```
1: The time series frequency has been rounded to support seasonal differencing. 
2: In value[[3L]](cond) :
  The chosen test encountered an error, so no seasonal differencing is
```

selected. Check the time series data.

This is what I am executing:

```
fit <- auto.arima(data,seasonal = TRUE, approximation = FALSE)
```

I have weekly time series data.

This is how `dput(data)` looks as follows:

```
structure(c(12911647L, 12618317L, 12827388L, 12967840L, 13264925L, 
13557838L, 13701131L, 13812463L, 13971928L, 13837658L, 13550635L, 
13022371L, 13507596L, 13456736L, 12992393L, 12831883L, 13262301L, 
12831691L, 12808893L, 12726330L, 11893457L, 12434051L, 12363464L, 
12077055L, 12107221L, 11986124L, 11997087L, 12264971L, 12164412L, 
12438279L, 12733842L, 12543251L, 12627134L, 12480153L, 12276238L, 
12443655L, 12497753L, 12279060L, 12549138L, 12308591L, 12416680L, 
12516725L, 12326545L, 12772578L, 12524848L, 13429830L, 14188044L, 
16611840L, 16476565L, 15659941L, 10785585L, 12150894L, 13436366L, 
12985213L, 13097555L, 13204872L, 13786040L, 13760281L, 13295389L, 
14734578L, 15043941L, 14821169L, 14361765L, 14300180L, 14357964L, 
14271892L, 13248168L, 13813784L, 14092489L, 14100024L, 13378374L, 
13225650L, 12582444L, 13267163L, 13026181L, 12747286L, 12707074L, 
12534595L, 12546094L, 13030406L, 12950360L, 12814398L, 13405187L, 
13277755L, 13142375L, 12742153L, 12610817L, 12267747L, 12570075L, 
12704157L, 12835948L, 12851893L, 12978880L, 13104906L, 12754018L, 
13213958L, 13584642L, 13963433L, 14471672L, 16312595L, 16630000L, 
16443882L, 11555299L, 12018373L, 13031876L, 13013945L, 13164137L, 
13313246L, 13652605L, 13803606L, 13308310L, 14466211L, 15092736L, 
15346015L, 14467260L, 14767785L, 13914271L, 14185070L, 13851028L, 
13605858L, 13597999L, 13876994L, 13026270L, 13113250L, 12288727L, 
12925846L, 13525010L, 12594472L, 12654512L, 12888260L), .Tsp = c(2016.00819672131, 
2018.48047598209, 52.1785714285714), class = "ts")
```

This is how I am reading data from the csv

```
read_data <- read.csv(file="data.csv", header=TRUE)
data_ts <- ts(read_data, freq=365.25/7,  start=decimal_date(ymd("2016-1-4")))
data <- data_ts[, 2:2]
```

This is the data in the csv:

```
Year    si_act
1/4/16  12911647
1/11/16 12618317
1/18/16 12827388
1/25/16 12967840
2/1/16  13264925
2/8/16  13557838
2/15/16 13701131
2/22/16 13812463
2/29/16 13971928
3/7/16  13837658
3/14/16 13550635
3/21/16 13022371
3/28/16 13507596
4/4/16  13456736
4/11/16 12992393
4/18/16 12831883
4/25/16 13262301
5/2/16  12831691
5/9/16  12808893
5/16/16 12726330
5/23/16 11893457
5/30/16 12434051
6/6/16  12363464
6/13/16 12077055
6/20/16 12107221
6/27/16 11986124
7/4/16  11997087
7/11/16 12264971
7/18/16 12164412
7/25/16 12438279
8/1/16  12733842
8/8/16  12543251
8/15/16 12627134
8/22/16 12480153
8/29/16 12276238
9/5/16  12443655
9/12/16 12497753
9/19/16 12279060
9/26/16 12549138
10/3/16 12308591
10/10/16    12416680
10/17/16    12516725
10/24/16    12326545
10/31/16    12772578
11/7/16 12524848
11/14/16    13429830
11/21/16    14188044
11/28/16    16611840
12/5/16 16476565
12/12/16    15659941
12/19/16    10785585
12/26/16    12150894
1/2/17  13436366
1/9/17  12985213
1/16/17 13097555
1/23/17 13204872
1/30/17 13786040
2/6/17  13760281
2/13/17 13295389
2/20/17 14734578
2/27/17 15043941
3/6/17  14821169
3/13/17 14361765
3/20/17 14300180
3/27/17 14357964
4/3/17  14271892
4/10/17 13248168
4/17/17 13813784
4/24/17 14092489
5/1/17  14100024
5/8/17  13378374
5/15/17 13225650
5/22/17 12582444
5/29/17 13267163
6/5/17  13026181
6/12/17 12747286
6/19/17 12707074
6/26/17 12534595
7/3/17  12546094
7/10/17 13030406
7/17/17 12950360
7/24/17 12814398
7/31/17 13405187
8/7/17  13277755
8/14/17 13142375
8/21/17 12742153
8/28/17 12610817
9/4/17  12267747
9/11/17 12570075
9/18/17 12704157
9/25/17 12835948
10/2/17 12851893
10/9/17 12978880
10/16/17    13104906
10/23/17    12754018
10/30/17    13213958
11/6/17 13584642
11/13/17    13963433
11/20/17    14471672
11/27/17    16312595
12/4/17 16630000
12/11/17    16443882
12/18/17    11555299
12/25/17    12018373
1/1/18  13031876
1/8/18  13013945
1/15/18 13164137
1/22/18 13313246
1/29/18 13652605
2/5/18  13803606
2/12/18 13308310
2/19/18 14466211
2/26/18 15092736
3/5/18  15346015
3/12/18 14467260
3/19/18 14767785
3/26/18 13914271
4/2/18  14185070
4/9/18  13851028
4/16/18 13605858
4/23/18 13597999
4/30/18 13876994
5/7/18  13026270
5/14/18 13113250
5/21/18 12288727
5/28/18 12925846
6/4/18  13525010
6/11/18 12594472
6/18/18 12654512
6/25/18 12888260
```

**Edit1 :**

I was able to read the data without any errors before, initially, I had 160 records & the model does not throw any error but, then for 80-20 test I removed the last 30 records and this error cropped up. Now also, if I run with all the data I don't get any error but is I run it with first 130 as 80% I get this error.

Comment: If you could edit your post to include the output of `dput(data)`, we may be able to help you.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Updated the post

Comment: Thank you. I get the same error, and I can't figure out what is happening. Using integer values for `start=2018` and `frequency=52` does not help, nor does dividing the series by 1e6 (sometimes this does help). Someone will likely need to step through `auto.arima()` line by line. Sorry I can't be more helpful, but I will nominate your question for reopening, since it is certainly [on topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I have updated the question with the code of how I am reading the data and also the data

Comment: OK, it has been reopened. (Feel the power of the golden tag badge! ;-) I also pinged Rob Hyndman, the author of the forecast package. He is unspeakably busy, but perhaps he will find the time to help. In the meantime, you could bypass the seasonal test, where the error occurs, by specifying `D=0` as a parameter to `auto.arima()` to suppress a seasonal model, or `D=1` to force seasonal differencing.

Comment: @StephanKolassa updated the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This warning (not an error) is informing you that the seasonal unit root test (used to select the number of seasonal differences, D) has errored.

Admittedly, the message is not very informative for why this has happened. In your case, an STL decomposition cannot be performed because your data contains less than two seasonal windows after the first seasonal difference. This is necessary to use the `nsdiffs(y, test = "seas")`, or `auto.arima(y, seasonal.test = "seas")` which are both defaults.

Note that the message informs you that `D=1` has been selected for this data. The test for `D=2` failed due to insufficient available data (generally one seasonal difference is sufficient, however you should check this visually or with other unit root tests).

I've now improved this message to now also include the error message for why the test has failed: https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/commit/eebea5ee93cd8b125d5220c54721895b57396157

```r
library(forecast)
fit <- auto.arima(data,seasonal = TRUE, approximation = FALSE)
#> Warning: The time series frequency has been rounded to support seasonal
#> differencing.
#> Warning: The chosen seasonal unit root test encountered an error when testing for the second difference.
#> From stl(): series is not periodic or has less than two periods
#> 1 seasonal differences will be used. Consider using a different unit root test.
fit
#> Series: data 
#> ARIMA(0,1,2)(0,1,0)[52] 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>           ma1      ma2
#>       -0.5560  -0.2496
#> s.e.   0.1124   0.1110
#> 
#> sigma^2 estimated as 1.199e+11:  log likelihood=-1090.71
#> AIC=2187.42   AICc=2187.74   BIC=2194.45
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot, also for the updated warning! Great to have you here!